# RemoteApp 2012 - App is flickering

Tags: windows-server-2012, rds, remoteapp

I have an application published on a Windows 2012 RDS server. Running the application from within a remote desktop session works fine, but when accessing via RemoteApp (tried on XP SP3, and 7 SP1), the application window flickers when moving the mouse, or clicking on buttons or dropdowns within the application, etc. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Technically the RemoteApp IS running in an RDP session, so I'm surprised there is different behavior.  Are the RDP session settings different for the deployed RDP of the RemoteApp vs. just using mstsc and creating a regular connection?  Possibly under the "Display" and the "Experience" tabs.

Comment: The session settings are the same. As I am using Windows 2012 for the session host and gateway, the normal tabs are not available when editing the RDP shortcut. I have toyed with editing the .rdp shortcut in notepad to no avail. Interestingly enough, I just tried on a Win8 computer and while the flicker exists, it isn't nearly as noticable.

Comment: You can see the rdp settings inside the RemoteApp administration on the server.  Look at the settings that are used for the deployed RDP "icon" and see if they differ vs. a normal new RDP session in Experience and Display.